# How can I include javascript with javascript_include_tag at the top of the page for a capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

I am trying to test one javascript class in a spec test with capybara.
I have static page player.haml in which I am loading the javascript class definition with javascript_include_tag. It looks like that

```
  .container
    = javascript_include_tag "../player"
    #player
```

My test looks like that

```
  it 'can autoplay a video' do
    visit player_path
    video = Fabricate(:video)
    options = { autoplay: true, ... }
    page.execute_script("var options = '#{options}';
    videoId = '#{video.id}'; var player = new Player(videoId, options);")
    expect(page).to have_content(video.title)
  end
```

The problem is that the javascript_include_tag is including the script at the bottom of the page and after the execute_script is invoke.
I tried with sleep after visiting the page, but the result was the same.
How can I load the class definition before to use execute_script?
Eventual bottleneck is the fact that the file with player definition is .coffee.erb. I can changed because it uses some settings from the application.

Comment: Does your capybara run javascript? Usually it doesn't unless you configure `js: true`

Comment: Can you wrap your javascript to run on the document ready event? I am not sure if it would work with capybara though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Comment: Yes, I have included js: true.

Comment: I tried page.execute_script("$(document).ready(function() { ...; });"), but also didn't work.